# So Jesus said the Spirit is God however the Holy Spirit is said to create God so how can the Holy Spirit be God if God was created by the Holy Spirit

Tags: trinity, spirit, existence-of-god

I am just confused about the Holy Trinity, Jesus said that the Spirit is God, however how can the Holy Spirit be God if it is also said that the Holy Spirit created God? Wouldn’t that mean that there was nothing and then instantly both God and the Holy Spirit just happened? Such as there isn’t and then there is, or another way to put that would be there’s nothing and then there’s something. Because I can’t see how/why Jesus would say that the Spirit is God when also the Bible says that the Holy Spirit created God. So how can God create himself before even being created?

Comment: Which passage are you referring to when you say that the "Bible says that the Holy Spirit created God"?

Comment: There is confusion here about Biblical language, which needs to be sorted out before your puzzle can be answered. Nobody says the Spirit is created. God is the Creator, which means he is not created himself. In the Supper Discourse, Jesus says that Father and Son both "send" the Spirit. In the Nicene Creed, the Spirit "proceeds" from the Father (and from the Son, for the non-Orthodox), which is theological language for "originates from them in some way which our minds cannot grasp, but it's not by creation"

Comment: Welcome to Christianity Stack Exchange.  To help you get started on this site, please take our Tour to see how we are different from other sites: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Different Christian traditions will have a different take on this. Do you have a specific tradition in mind for the answer?

Comment: @JBH From the tag and the terminology the OP uses, I think the Trinitarian tradition is implied, unless LDS also uses the term "The Holy Trinity".

Comment: @GratefulDisciple Possibly, but it's not how the Stack works. It's the OP's responsibility to be clear, not our responsibility to jump to conclusions and hope we're right.

Answer (score -1):

The Holy Spirit created the Father just as the Father created the Son. They share their divinity through relation and they are co equal in divinty. They have different thoughts because they are not seperate people. They are seperate IN their individualities. If my Dad has the last name Gregory, and then he has me, and my last name is Gregory, I am not the same exact individuality as my dad but I am a Gregory.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259). I would also recommend reading the [Help Center's](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) sections on asking and answering questions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: "The Holy Spirit created the Father just as the Father created the Son" No. It is a core principle that God is uncreated.